# oauth2 with rails and zapier

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, zapier, oauth-2.0

I have been assigned to a task where I suppose to use Zapier oauth2 with rails 4 application.whenever new prospect comes rest web hooks receive the data and send outbound mail with the data received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. Are you asking how to implement oauth2 in your Rails 4 app for Zapier integrations to work? If so, [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper) is a great gem for doing so. I've used it to implement oauth with Zapier.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right can you please guide me how to do it ?I have already made the developer zap following the oauth 2 documentation ,a test trigger and email as action .we are using doorkeeper for the oauth provider into our site .Please help me out...@John N.